# Resolve promise angular 5 and firebase

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, promise, angular5

I have a problem, when I try to return a value from method this return as undefined, this is the method:

```
getBrandName(keyVehicle): any{
    var nameBrand;
    let response=this.db.getBrand(keyVehicle);
    response.then((value)=>{
      nameBrand= value.name;
    })  
    return nameBrand;
  }
```

inside method I get value, but when return the value, this coming as undefined, please help me.

Comment: Are you trying to return the string name from the function, or a promise that's fulfilled with the string name?  As it stands now, it's difficult to tell what you meant because the function is defined to return `any`.  (BTW, you won't be able to return the string name because asynchronous APIs don't work like that.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways of doing this.

1) Return the promise.
You can return the promise and wait for completition in the code that calls this function.

```
getBrandName(keyVehicle): any {
    return this.db.getBrand(keyVehicle).then((value) => value.name);
}

// from other place
this.getBrandName("foo").then(nameBrand => console.log(nameBrand));
```

2) Pass a callback (This might not be a good idea, but the chance is there so you can do it).

```
getBrandName(keyVehicle, callback): any {
    this.db.getBrand(keyVehicle)
        .then((value) => value.name)
        .then(brandName => callback(brandName));
}

// from other place
this.getBrandName("foo", brandName => console.log(brandName));
```

3) Use `async/await` (maybe the recomended way)

```
async getBrandName(keyVehicle): any {
    const response = await this.db.getBrand(keyVehicle);
    return response.name;
}
```

Either way, remember that this is a pure Javascript/Promise question, no matter if you are using angular, firebase or any other tool.

Answer (score 0):

That is correct. If you return `nameBrand` right away, the initial value is null due to `var nameBrand`.

Only when `response.then` is called, you then populate the local variable `nameBrand`.

You can try the following,

```
export class ABC {
    nameBrand = [];
    getBrandName() {
        this.db.getBrand().then((value) => {
            this.nameBrand = value;
        }
    }
}
```

But you still will get `this.nameBrand` populated after the `http` call is finished, not just right after `getBrandName()`.

Makes sense, this is an `async` call.